# Mysterious gap between two words doesn't get selected. Word 2011 Mac

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using Word 2011 on Mac.

There is this gap between two words within a line of text, a little bigger than a space. It is not a Tab, it does not delete and it does NOT get highlighted when I drag the mouse over the whole line where it is located. I mean, the whole line gets the highlight color except that gap, which remains white. I've erased the whole line, typed again, but the gap stays there in the same place. Can't figure out where it comes from. When I copied the full document text to a new document the gap disappeared. But I need the original because there are too many pages with graphics and annotations, which did not copy into the new document.

Comment: Click "Show all nonprinting characters" button on the toolbar and see if there is a some kind of hidden character there.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're saying that you can delete the text and retype it, and the problem recurs.  What happens if you type the problematic text in a new paragraph?  How much do you need to retype?  A whole sentence?  A few words?  A few characters?  Can you tell us what you type?  Can you upload an image (screen snapshot)?

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible that the text is JUSTIFIED?

That would stretch the text giving the impression that there was gaps between words.